# Understanding Landsat 7 Layer Properties

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat-7

I have a Landstat 7 band 1 layer and am trying to understand exactly what it is showing. Specifically, if I go to the  layer properties, under source there is an "Extent" section which shows 4 numbers, (Top, Left, Right, Bottom).

What exactly do these mean in the context of remote sensing?

[image]

Comment: Please use the Picture button to embed your screenshot into the body of your question.  Potential answerers will not always follow links to view them.

Comment: If you google "arcgis raster properties" you will get plenty of web pages explaining what these mean.  I found for example http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-dataset-properties.htm

Comment: thanks that tells me Extent is describing boundaries but I don't really understand what these boundaries mean in the context of remote sensing or landsat-7.

Comment: If you draw a rectangle, it's the coordinates of the corners, that's the extent. Top, left, right, bottom.

Comment: The 4 numbers are just the coordinates of the Top, Left, Right, and Bottom of your Landsat image in the refeernce system of your data and in the units of it (you could check it in the same "Source" tab).